# Docker hosted Rails application cannot find Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

My GitLab Pipeline runs successfully but the Docker container exits within seconds of it being created.

Running `$ docker container logs eops_staging` on the hosting server outputs:

```
$ docker container logs eops_staging
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:23:in `build': /usr/src/app/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:155:in `definition'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

I can run the container successfully on my development machine.

The command I use to fire up the Docker container is

```
$ docker --context dockerapps compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml up -d
```

I am new to using Docker and hosting Docker containers. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you -Chris

**Fix**

I have updated the below files and code to reflect the state when issue was resolved.

**Dockerfile.staging**

```
FROM ruby:2.1.6

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get --force-yes install -y --no-install-recommends  \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git \
    libaio-dev

# Solves 'Connection time out' on server when running git clone when running
# bundle install cmd.
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

# Copy Vendor oracle to '/usr/lib/oracle/'
ADD vendor/oracle /usr/lib/oracle/
# Point to where Oracle Instant Client files are
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_8'
# To resolve warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US-ASCII, when using oracle_enhanced.
ENV NLS_LANG='AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15'
RUN echo "The ENV variable value is $NLS_LANG"

ARG APP_HOME=/usr/src/app

# Make this the current working directory for the image. So we can execute Rails \
# cmds against image.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# CD or change into the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Gemfile Caching Trick
# Note: When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must
#       be a directory and end with a /
# 1. This creates a separate, independent layer. Docker's cache for this layer
#    will only be busted if either of these two files (Gemfile & Gemfile.lcok) change.
COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/


# Configure Bundler to use an explicit, known directory for installing gems.
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems


# Setup bundler version specifically
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION='1.9.6'
RUN gem install bundler --no-document -v '1.9.6'
RUN bundle install

# ADD/COPY app files from local directory into container so they are baked into the image.
# The source path on our local machine is always relative to where the Dockerfile is located.
ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN ls -la .

# Start the Rails server by default (bake it into the image).
CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.staging.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    # build => tells Compose where to find the Dockerfile it should use
    #          to build our image. The path we specify is relative to
    #          the docker-compose.yml file.
    #          So builds an image for any service with a 'build' directive.
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.staging
    image: eops_app:staging
    container_name: eops_staging
    #todo restart: always
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
      PIDFILE: /tmp/pids/server.pid
    tmpfs:
      # tmpfs mount is temporary and persists in the host memory.
      # When container stops, the tmpfs mount is removed, and all files in it will be gone.
      - /tmp/pids/
    env_file:
      - .env/app
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
stages:
  - publish
  - deploy

publish-to-staging:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'docker_dev'
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker image build -f Dockerfile.staging -t registry.example.com/cals-it-acs/hr-eops/docker_app/eops_app:staging .
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSW | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER registry.example.com --password-stdin
    - docker push registry.example.com/cals-it-acs/hr-eops/docker_app/eops_app:staging

deploy-to-staging:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'docker_dev'
  script:
    # Revoke all permissions for group and others from the private key, such
    # that only the owner can use it. Required otherwise SSH refuses to work
    # with the private key.
    - chmod og= $ID_ECDSA
    # In each SSH statement you are executing command on the remote server.
    # To do so, you authenticate with your private key.
    - ssh -i $ID_ECDSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deploy@dock.cals.wisc.edu "docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSW registry.example.com"
    - ssh -i $ID_ECDSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deploy@dock.cals.wisc.edu "docker pull registry.example.com/cals-it-acs/hr-eops/docker_app/eops_app:staging"
    # Remove docker container if it exists
    - ssh -i $ID_ECDSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deploy@dock.cals.wisc.edu "docker container rm -f eops_staging || true"
    # Following two commands are for debugging purposes only.
    - ssh -i $ID_ECDSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deploy@dock.cals.wisc.edu "docker ps"
    - ssh -i $ID_ECDSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no deploy@dock.cals.wisc.edu "docker network list"
    # Copy env file ...
    - cp $EOPS_ENV .env/app
    # Start container
    - docker --context dockerapps compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml up -d

deploy-to-production:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'docker_main'
  script:
    - echo "deploying to production . . ."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was bringing in development config into the docker-compose.staging.yml that shouldn't have there. In removing the "volumes" section, resolved the issue where the Docker container would run successfully after being started. I have updated the files and code (above) to reflect the state where the container was running successfully after being started.